# Probability of selecting all defective parts

Tags: combinations

In a problem we are faced with 22 items from a shipment. It is known that 7 of the items are defective. What is the probability of selecting all defective items from a draw of 7. What is the probability of a draw where none of the items defective. I suspect both answers are the same but I could very well be wrong.

The way I see it -

P(E)=(P(one Defective)=7/22=0.3181818182
P(E)=(P(all defective)^7)=0.0003301623

Am I even approaching this problem from the right direction?

Comment: **Hint :** There are $\binom{22}{7}$ draws of $7$, but only one such that you select all defective items. Also, if you selected no defective item, then you selected items from the remaining $22-7 = 15$ others.

Answer (score 1):

There are [$\binom{22}{7} = 170,544$](https://www.google.com/search?q=22+choose+7) ways to draw seven parts.  There is only *one* way to get all parts being defective (you have to draw every last one as being defective: $\binom{7}{7} = 1$).

On the other hand, there are $22 - 7 = 15$ non-defective parts, so there are [$\binom{15}{7} = 6,435$](https://www.google.com/search?q=15+choose+7) ways to draw *all* non-defective parts.

**Additional Details**

This can be done by either permutations *or* combinations although combinations is generally more compact and intuitive and thus you should try to think in terms of combinations for most problems--*but not all problems*.

To do this using permutations, we note that you have a $\frac{7}{22}$ chance of drawing a defective part, then it's $\frac{6}{21}$, then $\frac{5}{20}$, etc.  This gives:

$$
p = \frac{7}{22}\cdot\frac{6}{21}...\cdot\frac{1}{16} = \frac{7!\cdot15!}{22!}
$$

However, you will notice that this equals the explicit form of [$\frac{1}{\binom{22}{7}}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Factorial_formula):

$$
\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}
$$

We then would get:

$$
\frac{1}{\binom{22}{7}} = \frac{1}{\frac{22!}{7!(22 - 7)!}} = \frac{7!\cdot 15!}{22!}
$$

For getting all seven as being non-defective then we get:

$$
p = \frac{15}{22}\cdot\frac{14}{21}...\frac{9}{16} = \frac{15!\cdot15!}{22!\cdot 8!}
$$

Again, if we write the above combinations, we'll get the same thing:

$$
\frac{\binom{15}{7}}{\binom{22}{7}} = \frac{7!\cdot15!}{22!}\cdot \frac{15!}{7!(15 - 7)!} = \frac{15!\cdot15!}{22!\cdot8!}
$$

Comment: @user140705 Note that your reasoning is incorrect. However, it can be made correct as follows : picking all $7$ defective items is equivalent to picking one at each one of the $7$ picks. But at the second pick, there are $21$ items left and $6$ defective items remaining if you picked one at first. Continuing this reasoning, one gets that the probability of picking the $7$ defective items is $\frac{7}{22} \times \frac{6}{21} \times \frac{5}{20} \times \frac{4}{19} \times \frac{3}{18} \times \frac{2}{17} \times \frac{1}{16}$. You can check it also equals $\frac{1}{\binom{22}{7}}$.

Comment: Quick question. The answer above is confusing for ways to draw 7 non-defective items. Both calculations come up with 170544 ways. However, we know for a fact at least 1 way has all seven defective. Surely there are other possibilities for drawing 2 defective, or 3 defective, et cetera reducing the overall possible ways from 170544.

Comment: @user140705 See my edited answer (I initially had $\binom{22}{15}$ which is not correct and makes no sense if you think about it).

Comment: No worries. I thought I had overlooked something. Thank you both greatly.

Comment: @user140705 well you caught the obvious mistake: how could getting all non-defective have probability $1$?  It doesn't pass the "smell" test (i.e. it's obviously incorrect which you noticed).